# Orbeon 3.9 ressources management

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to upgrade orbeon 3.7 to orbeon 3.9 and I found that now orbeon access in a different way the ressources.

In orbeon 3.7 I changed WEB-INF/ressources/page-flow.xml like this:

```
  <!-- Dispatch request to a specific application -->
  <page id="apps" path-info="/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).*" matcher="oxf:perl5-matcher" model="/${1}/${2}/${3}/page-flow.xml"/>
```

to access this way 127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/myapp/user/role

But with this configuration orbeon 3.9 did not find the css and images

my application is under WEB-INF/ressources/myapp/"folder"/"subfolder"

In 3.9 I configure page-flow.xml in the same way and I realize that if I copy the application to WEB-INF/ressources/apps/ it find the css and images but is not a solution since i have to put my application in two different locations.

Do know how could configure orbeon 3.9 so it behaves the same way orbeon 3.7 or at least to place the app in the same folder as the css and images?

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the orbeon 3.9 documentation that solve my problem:

---

Default app path prepended for resources

The oxf.url-rewriting.app-prefix property is now set to /apps instead of being blank.

With Orbeon Forms if you write /foo/bar as a path to a page, this is meant to reach an application called foo under the /apps resources folder. In particular, the page flow /apps/foo/page-flow.xml is retrieved.

On the other hand, before Orbeon Forms 3.9, if you wrote /foo/bar.gif, the resource was searched under /foo/bar.gif instead of /apps/foo/bar.gif.

This forced you, if you wanted to store resources together with pages, to prepend /apps to all your resources paths, but not to your page paths.

The change to the oxf.url-rewriting.app-prefix property fixes that, by adding the /apps prefix automatically if missing. For this feature to work properly, all non-platform (i.e. non-Orbeon) resources, including CSS, JavaScript, and images, should be located alongside your application under /apps/[application].

You can turn off this feature by setting the property to an empty string in your properties-local.xml:

```
 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.url-rewriting.app-prefix" value="/apps"/>
```

Regards

Comment: Yes I think you figured it out!